# How to convert json stringify output to string and show this to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

my code is :

```
$("#Button").on('click', function () {
     var rowindexes = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindexes');
     var boundrows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getboundrows');
     var selectedrows = new Array();
     for(var i =0; i < rowindexes.length; i++)
     {
         var row = boundrows[rowindexes[i]];
         selectedrows.push(row);
     }

    var a=JSON.stringify(selectedrows);
    $(jQuery.parseJSON(a)).each(function() {  
    var ID = this.EmployeeID;
    var TITLE = this.Title;
    //alert(ID+TITLE);

    $('#comment').val(ID).split('\n');

});
```

i'm show this data using `alert on javascript` this code working correctly, 
when i'm show this data using `textarea`, this code not working correctly
only one data to show for me
please give me a solution for this problems
thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `stringify` if you immediately `parse` afterwards. Just do `$(selectedrows)`, or better: `$.each(selectedrows,...)`.

Comment: `$('#comment').text(ID).split('\n');` ? try `text` instead of `val` ?

Comment: @Jigar thanks for your comment, i try with text not work

Comment: @FelixKling give me a sample for your answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("comment").value = "ID";
```

Comment: Thanks problems solved with this : var comments = '';                              and this :                                                                                         comments = comments +  ID + TITLE + '\n';

Answer (score 0):

Because when `$('#comment').val(ID)` will change current contents in `#comment` to the `ID`, so after the forEach iterations, your `#comment` will only show last `ID`.

You can define a string, and append the data to that string in each iteration, then set the string to `#comment`, when every data is processed.

```
$("#Button").on('click', function () {
     var rowindexes = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindexes');
     var boundrows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getboundrows');
     var selectedrows = new Array();
     for(var i =0; i < rowindexes.length; i++)
     {
         var row = boundrows[rowindexes[i]];
         selectedrows.push(row);
     }

    var comments = '';
    // As Felix Kling says, you don't have to convert the selectedrows to
    // string then convert them back. just use $.each(selectedrows, ....
    // is enough.
    $.each(selectedrows, function() {  
        var ID = this.EmployeeID;
        var TITLE = this.Title;
        //alert(ID+TITLE);

        // Append new comment to the comments string.
        comments = comments + ID + TITLE + '\n';
    });

    // Set the `#comment`'s value to comments after all comment is append to comments.
    $('#comment').val(comments);
});
```

Demo:

```js
// A fake data that has attr EmployeeID and Title to fit the logic in $.each
var fake = [
  {EmployeeID: 1, Title: 'a'},
  {EmployeeID: 2, Title: 'b'},
  {EmployeeID: 3, Title: 'c'},
  {EmployeeID: 4, Title: 'd'},
];
  

$("#Button").on('click', function () {   
  var comments = '';
  $.each(fake, function() {  
    var ID = this.EmployeeID;
    var TITLE = this.Title;
    //alert(ID+TITLE);
    comments = comments +  ID + TITLE + '\n';
  }); 
  $('#comment').val(comments);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
<button id="Button">show</button>
```